# Bind <mat slide toggle> using [(ngModel)] with a string value in HTML

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a material slide toggle button and it is two way bind with a string variable having a value "true" or "false" using [(ngModel)], the button updates the value of variable correctly when i toggle it, but for the first time when it is loaded in DOM, it always shows its state to true even if the value in the variable is "false".

```
<div *ngIf="agent.attributes[i].type == 'Boolean'">
  <mat-slide-toggle [checked]="agent.attributes[i].value == 'true' ? true : false" 
                  [(ngModel)]="agent.attributes[i].value">{{agent.attributes[i].value}}</mat-slide-toggle>
                </div>
```

[this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAWd6.png)

Comment: Can you create stackblitz link to reproduce the issue? seems you are having a problem with array it self

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you are binding string value to ngModel that needs to be boolean for check, so change it to:

```
<div>
  <mat-slide-toggle 
      [checked]="agent.attributes[i].value === 'true' ? true : false"
      (change)="setValue( i , $event )">
      {{agent.attributes[i].value}}
  </mat-slide-toggle>
</div>
```

ts code:

```
setValue(i , e){
    if(e.checked){
        this.agent.attributes[i].value = 'true'
   }else{
        this.agent.attributes[i].value = 'false'
   }
}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-ydddku)

Comment: "attributes is an array of object like this {
        "_id": "5bf7e1be80c05307d06423c2",
        "agentId": "awais",
        "attributes": [
            {
                "name": "Marketing",
                "type": "Boolean",
                "value": "true",
            },
            {
                "name": "English",
                "type": "Proficiency",
                "value": "7",
            }
        ],
        "__v": 0
    }

Comment: @RazaEllahi OK, i didn't need to know what attributes is and just tried an example you can put your own attributes.

Comment: i got an error ,  "Cannot read property '2' of undefined"  , 2 is index value

Comment: which line causes error? it seems you are using ngfor.

Comment: i uses *ngFor in html

Comment: oh I got it, in agents variable i have a lot of agents, so i need to get the particular agent, i got it, thanks a lot you solved my problem on which i spend 2 days

Comment: you're welcome, i updated the DEMO too, you can accept my answer.

Comment: I tried to vote the answer but i can't , my repo not good for stackOverFlow, any how thanks a lot once again

Comment: @RazaEllahi yes but you can accept the answer of your questions by selecting a tick under the vots.

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your code is that your `[(ngModel)]` binding is overwriting the `[checked]` binding. Remove the `[(ngModel)]` binding and you can see that the `[checked]` binding works just fine.

Since your `value` property is a string with a value of `'false'` or `'true'`, the `[(ngModel)]` binding will evaluate that to true in both cases.

Ideally your `value` property would be a `boolean`. Why does it need to be a string?

With the property as a `boolean` you could even get rid of the `[checked]` binding like so:

```
<div *ngIf="agent.attributes[i].type == 'Boolean'">
  <mat-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="agent.attributes[i].value">{{agent.attributes[i].value}}</mat-slide-toggle>
</div>
```

If it has to be of type `string` then you can use a getter/setter in your component like in this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-v5-qeufiq?file=app%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: the type of variable is strictly string , it cant be changed because some times a string value have to store in it, if i remove ngModel all things goes fine but than, how can i bind it with the variable.

Comment: The part about removing `[(ngModel)]` was only to showcase that your `[checked]` binding was indeed working. If it has to be of type string you can use a getter/setter in your component, see the edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

I tried here with an example a little bit different, but I hope it will help you.
According to the docs:
https://material.angular.io/components/slide-toggle/api
This component has a Output propertie named change wich:

> An event will be dispatched each time the slide-toggle changes its
>   value.

You can try to add:

(change)="agent.attributes[i].value= !agent.attributes[i].value"

As you can see here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b77drk?file=app/slide-toggle-configurable-example.html